# How to pass parameter to jqgrid from another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, parameters

I have dynamic button of reports name,every time the user click the button,it will display the search fields (start date,end date) which is applicable to all reports,all reports have their different page to display with their own grid and now how can I pass parameters and open the corresponding page of the report and load the jqgrid. I've been stock with this passing parameters to "OnlineSales" page and then load the grid. Thanks in advance for helping!

After I click the search button what will be the syntax for calling the OnlineSales page and passing the parameters and then display the data in grid.

```
$('#SearchButton').click(function () {
            var _StartDate = $("#StartDate").val();
            var _EndDate = $("#EndDate").val();
});
```

call OnlineSales view with parameters

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OnlineSales";
}

@*GRID*@
    <div id="table" class="table">
        <table id="List" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <div id="Pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
    </div>
@*GRID*@

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery("#List").jqGrid({
            url: 'local',
            postData: { start_date: '', end_date: ''},
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: [
                  'First Name',
                  'Middle Name',
                  'Last Name',
                  'Email',
                  'Mobile Number'],
            colModel: [
                  { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'MiddleName', index: 'MiddleName', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                  { name: 'MobileNumber', index: 'MobileNumber', width: 80, align: 'left' }],
            pager: jQuery('#Pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
            sortname: 'FirstName',
            width: '1005',
            sortorder: "asc",
            sorttype: 'int',
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 'auto',
            shrinkToFit: false,
            cache: false,
            caption: 'Online Sales'
        });
        jQuery("#List").jqGrid('navGrid', '#Pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true });

    });
</script>
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult OnlineSales(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, DateTime start_date, DateTime end_date)
        {
            _DashboardDataAccess = new DashboardDataAccess(0);
            List<OnlineSales> _OnlineSales = _DashboardDataAccess.OnlineSales(start_date, end_date);

            var result = _OnlineSales.AsQueryable().AsEnumerable<OnlineSales>();

            int count = result.Count();
            result = result.Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows);
            int pagecount = (count % rows) == 0 ? (count / rows) : (count / rows) + 1;

            var ReportList = (from r in result
                              select new
                              {
                                  cell = new string[] {
                                  r.FirstName,
                                  r.MiddleName,
                                  r.LastName,
                                  r.Email,
                                  r.MobileNumber
                                  }
                              });
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = pagecount,
                page = page,
                records = count,
                rows = ReportList.ToArray()
            };

            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you query properly, try this...

Store the `StartDate` and `EndDate` in a `Session Variables`, then you can check for `Session Variables` where you are sending the `grid data`, and according to `Session Variables` you can then build your query. You will also need to check for `null`, and if `Session Variables` are `null` then you can return the result without `Search Parameters`.

And then just navigate to the page where your `grid` for the selected report is. Then grid will load the data according to the search parameters(from the session).

**Edit1**

Another Way:

Define two hidden fields in HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenStartDate" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenEndDate" value="">
```

Then Set the value to hidden fields in your function:

```
$('#SearchButton').click(function () {
    $('#hiddenStartDate').val($("#StartDate").val());
    $('#hiddenEndDate').val($("#EndDate").val());
    //Submit the form where you are accepting the request for grid for building query and sending data
    //Access values of hidden fields
});
```

Comment: Thank you but I cant display the OnlineSales page with data